# gZIP with AWS cloudFront and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression, gzip, amazon-cloudfront

CloudFront offers [compression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html) (gZIP) for certain file types from the origin. My architecture looks like this:

[image: Architecture]

So, the requirements for the files to get compressed in cloudFront are:

**1.** Have to enable `Compress Objects Automatically` option in cloudFront's cache behaviour settings.

**2.** **content-type** and **content-length** has to be returned by **S3**. **S3** sends these headers by default. I have cross checked this.

**3.** The received file type must be one of the [file types](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html#compressed-content-cloudfront-file-types) listed by cloudFront. In my case, I want to compress `app.bundle.js` which comes under `application/javascript` (content-type) and it is also present in the supported file-types of cloudFront.

I guess above are the only requirements to get a gZipped version of the files to browser. Even after having the above things, gzip does not work for me. Any ideas, what am I missing?

Comment: Did you meet the file size minimum?

Comment: I mean how to gZIP the file using cloudFront and S3. Yes, Long story short, need to reduce the file size

Comment: Cloudfront only compresses files of a certain size.  If your file is below that size, it won’t compress it.

Comment: Good Point. I am sure my file is between the minimum and maximum range.